# Magento create multiple "mini-search box" in products page and main.page

Tags: php, magento, search

I want to have **one mini-search box** in the **products page** and one **mini-search box** in the **home-page** in my Magento 1.7.2.

These mini-search box are called from the **local.xml** (in my own template ofcourse)

like this below:

```
    <reference name="left">
             <block type="core/template" name="top.search" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml" after="sibling.blockName"/>
    </reference>

   <reference name="right">
             <block type="core/template" name="top.search_main" template="catalogsearch/form.mini_main.phtml" after="sibling.blockName"/>
   </reference>
```

I cannot make the **top.search_main** to apear in the main page...
How should I write the  **reference name="right"** ?

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi use this may it will helps you go to catalogsearch.xml and replace with this

```
<reference name="header">
        <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

to `<reference name="right">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
        </reference>` 
for product and user bellow tag to remove this block from different handles like

```
 <review_product_list> <remove name="top.search" /> </review_product_list>
```

for home page i need details how you calling the home page, but try this for home page

```
{{block type="core/template" name="home.search" as="homeSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"}}
```

put it on home pags content section from admin and than change the css for search according to the page

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate...! Is there a way to call "home.search" NOT from cms but to call it from the 1column.phtml. I want to call it in more more programmatically way,but what you have suggested work also. Any opinion on this ?

Comment: @kost try this <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: <div class="col-main">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
     
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>  

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/for‌​m.mini.phtml')->toHtml(); ?> 
       
</div>   @Darasanthi this is my code in 1column.phtml..It doesnt run

Comment: @kost This is working in all layout of mine, can you make some debug on it, call it on 2column-left.phtml ya 2column-right.phtml

Comment: it works thanks!! A last question though...Which of the two files is better to call the mini search on your opinion ...local.xml or catalogsearch.xml ?

Comment: @kost it's good to call in local.xml, but sometime its not working, so we can make changes in catalogsearch.xml